# Website to PDF with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wget, pdf, conversion, html

I am trying to convert the manual http://101.wacom.com/UserHelp/en/TOC/CTH-490.html into a PDF.

In Arch Linux I tried:

```
wget --recursive --page-requisites --domains wacom.com  http://101.wacom.com/UserHelp/en/TOC/CTH-490.html
wkhtmltopdf 101.wacom.com/UserHelp/en/TOC/CTH-490.html foo.pdf
```

and also replacing `wkhtmltopdf` with:

```
htmldoc --webpage -f foo.pdf  101.wacom.com/UserHelp/en/TOC/CTH-490.html
```

I get just the first page (almost blank with `htmldoc`).

wkhtmltopdf is version 0.12.5 from the community repository.
HTMLDOC is version 1.9.8.

Answer (score 1):

That is a dynamic page, an empty shell created by HTML that loads its contents via scripting. If you look at the HTML source and understand how it works you might be able to download the information as you planned, by chunks, but you will have to piece them together.

You are trying to scrape a dynamic site, and a good candidate tool for that is python and some additional libraries.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python#26440563) might help.

Comment: I don't think scripts are the problem. wkhtmltopdf can generate the first page with full content, including the lateral div with TOC links to other pages. The problem is adding all the pages.